# Keep RID in sync with multiple tabs for Strophe js connection

Tags: connection, chat, openfire, strophe

We are trying to implement a chat application where we are using strophe js for http-bind. Everything works fine, the only problem we are facing is with keeping connection alive with multiple tabs. I am not getting how to keep RID in sync when multiple tabs are open. Please help!!

Comment: Have you tried using a cookie?

Comment: Yes Mark, i tried cookie, but i am not able to keep the connection active in both the tabs. It fails when pings happens at the same time in both tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each requesting resource should have it's own resource name. In your instance, each tab should have it's own resource name and connection.

```
username@jabber.servername.com/tab1
username@jabber.servername.com/tab2
```

You will then need to cc any messages to each resource to keep them up to date with messages. See: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0280.html. Each resource will then have it's own RID.

Comment: thank you so much this work in terms of keeping connection alive. I have one more question, not able to get online people presence in both the tabs. Is there anything else i need to do ?